# DropDownList DataSource set to EF bindingsource gives "The property 'BackupFileID' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified."

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, binding

I have a combo box(DropDownList) with a data source bound to `backupFilesBindingSource`, which displays backup file paths as members of the list. When the selection in the dropdown changes, it loads an image into a `PictureBox` on the form.

In my `form_load` I have the following:

```
            backupFilesBindingSource.DataSource = this._Entities.RecordBackupFilePaths
                                                            .Where(x => x.RecordID == _selectedRecord.RecordID);
            if (_uiImagesQComboBox.SelectedIndex == backupFilesBindingSource.Count - 1)
            {
                // Just to ensure the image is displayed
                _uiImagesQComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
            _uiImagesQComboBox.SelectedIndex = (backupFilesBindingSource.Count - 1);
```

When I have more than one backup file, when the form loads, I get the error:

> "The property 'BackupFileID' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified."

Which is thrown at `ReportPropertyChanging("BackupFileID");`

```
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=true, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.Int32 BackupFileID
    {
        get
        {
            return _BackupFileID;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_BackupFileID != value)
            {
                OnBackupFileIDChanging(value);
                ReportPropertyChanging("BackupFileID");
                _BackupFileID = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
                ReportPropertyChanged("BackupFileID");
                OnBackupFileIDChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

DropDownList Binding settings: 
[image: DropDownList Binding settings]

I understand that the `BackupFileID` property is a key, but I can't understand where it is attempted to be modified, since essentially all I am doing is changing the selected item in the dropdownlist.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Does your DropDownList have anything in DataBindings? Do you have anything bound to `SelectedValue`, for example?